# Convert png images to lossy avif

Tags: imagemagick, avif

I try to compress my ~1MB pngs to get a smaller image.

When I compress my images to jpeg with:

```
for i in card*.png ; do convert -resize 445x625 -background white -flatten "$i" ../medium/"${i%.*}.jpg" ; done
```

they end up about 100kb

So I tried

```
for i in card*.png ; do echo $i; convert -resize 445x625 "$i" ../medium/"${i%.*}.avif" ; done
```

which results in avif images ~400kb, I guess because they are losslessly compressed.

How do I create lossy compressed avif images? And what would be a useful quality level to get images with the text still clearly readeable?

*(I use ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 on Ubuntu)*

Comment: I do not believe that avif is fully developed in ImageMagick. But you can try -density X, where X is between 0 and 100. The lower. the value, the more compressed. But that is just a guess, since avif is not even listed in the list of formats. Also it may only be implemented in testing in IM 7. You are using IM 6

Comment: Sorry, I meant -quality X not -density X

Comment: -quality has no effect, when converting to aviff

Comment: Too bad.  Sorry, but as I said it is still in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### libheif

You can install

```
apt install libheif-examples
```

and then use `heif-enc` to create ***heif*** files with:

```
for i in card*.png ; do echo $i; heif-enc "$i" -o "${i%.*}.avif" ; done
```

If you need ***avif*** format, you need to compile the latest version of [libheif](https://github.com/strukturag/libheif), which has the `-A` option to create avif files.
(There is a section in the README there how to build it on your system. But at least on Ubuntu this is not leading to a running `heif-enc`)

---

#### Better use `avifenc`:

```
# Install Homebrew
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
sudo apt install zsh # needed for this pspecific package install
brew install joedrago/repo/avifenc
```

Now you have the tool to create avif files with the syntax:

```
avifenc [options] input.[jpg|jpeg|png|y4m] output.avif
```

(use `avifenc --speed 4 --min 20 --max 22 -j 8` to get a higher compression and use all 8 cores)

Comment: `avifenc` spits a 'segmentation fault' on Debian stable. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried all. The only input and output. With and without -o as well as several found here and elsewhere. I guess it's just broken. I might compile the source or file a bug at the Debian maintainer. It's Debian. Most of times everything is good and then something is just broke. S* happens.

Comment: Now it complains, that there is no codec...

Comment: Don’t use this custom `avifenc` package because it’s outdated; instead use Homebrew’s official one: `brew install libavif`.