# Add avif images in HTML using nginx as a server

Tags: nginx, avif

I created some avif images with `heif-anc`:

```
for i in card*.png ; do heif-enc "$i" -o "${i%.*}.avif" ; done
```

But When I added them to my website, it just proposed to download the image instead.

Then I [enabled avif images in my nginx-config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64293234/how-to-enable-avif-support-for-a-server) with

```
http {
  types {
    image/avif avif;
  }
  ...
```

Now it tries to display the image, but they seem to be broken. If you call it directly, Firefox with successfully enabled avif support shows this error message:

> avif could not be displayed because it contains errors

Here: you can see the avif file I try to serve:

https://cards.incantata.de/cdn/avif_orig/card_63.avif

Do I have to create the avif image in a different way so firefox can display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox can't display HEIF/HEIC images yet.

In order to encode AVIF via `heif-enc`, add `-A` parameter. When you omit -A parameter, HEIC file is encoded.

Alternative way of encoding AVIF is to use `avifenc` from libavif package.

Comment: great! avifenc did the job! I explained how to install it on Ubuntu here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65765495/1069083

Comment: heif-enc has no Option -A in the latest version from the Ubuntu repository